# Bootstrap "Mobile first" behavior

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

There is someting i definitly don't get with the "mobile first default behavior" in bootstrap 3 :

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

How can Extra small device be the default behavior if there is no break point at 480px ? I understand the default for font-size and stuff, but for the grid system, if a want a 6/12 sized block between 480px and 768px (col-xs-6), to become 12/12 at less than 480px then you just can't do it ? I need you guys to explain the concept, because i don't see how this can be a mobile first behavior.

PS : I know the community provide stylesheets to get a 480px breakpoint, and i can do it myself too, but considerating the fact bootstrap is a great lib, it seem weird to have this kind of trouble, maybe i just don't get the point here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211887/css-responsive-issue-with-ipad-mini-in-non-landscape-mode-vertical/23212258#23212258

Answer (score 0):

The general assumption is that content is displayed the same way on every device / browser window that's smaller than 768px. If you need to distinguish below that breakpoint, you have a few options:

1. Write your own CSS that covers your needs in addition to Bootstrap's defaults. Be careful not to run into problems with code order or specifity that might cause the wrong styles to take precedence
2. Bootstrap is customizable, among other things you can [adjust Bootstraps breakpoints](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints) to your needs.
3. If you're feeling adventurous, always on the bleeding edge or (depending on your use-case) just reckless, you could also use [Bootstrap 4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/), since it introduces a 4th breakpoint (which gives you 5 different sizes) to better target devices in landscape mode.

Here's the relevent CSS from Bootstrap's V4-Docs, don't be confused they switched from `px` to `em` as their primary unit for measurements:

```
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 34em)
// No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap

// Small devices (landscape phones, 34em and up)
@media (min-width: 34em) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 48em and up)
@media (min-width: 48em) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 62em and up)
@media (min-width: 62em) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 75em and up)
@media (min-width: 75em) { ... }
```